# How to create a simple host component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, I am reading https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-

[image]

```
<!-- "The sum of 1 + 1 is not 4" -->
<p>The sum of 1 + 1 is not {{1 + 1 + getVal()}}.</p>
```

I have component `product-list` has

[image]

**File `product-list.component.html`**

```
<h2>Products</h2>

<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <h3><a [title]="product.name + ' details'">{{product.name}}</a></h3>
  <p *ngIf="product.description">Description: {{product.description}}</p>
  <button (click)="share()">Share</button>
  <p>The sum of 1 + 1 is not {{1 + 1 + getVal()}}.</p>
</div>
```

**File `product-list.component.ts`**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {products} from '../products';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent {
  products = products;

  share() {
    window.alert('The product has been shared!');
  }
}
```

How to create `getVal()` host component?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value for each product?

Comment: No, I just need an example, not need put in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare the method into your component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {products} from '../products';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent {
  products = products;

  share() {
    window.alert('The product has been shared!');
  }

  getVal() {
     // DO YOUR WORK
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the function in the `.ts` file with a return type.

```
getVal(){

return "your value"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProductListComponent` itself is the host-component using the `product-list.component.html` as its template. You only need to create a function in the `ProductListComponent` class and the html can use that function.

```
class ProductListComponent {
    getVal() {
       // return something from here to display in html
       return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code it will help you. It's nothing you have to create **getVal()**  function.

**product-list.component.ts**

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {products} from '../products';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-product-list',
 templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent {
  products = products;
  //count = <any number or you requirement value>
  count = 5;
  share() {
    window.alert('The product has been shared!');
  }

 getVal(){
 return this.count;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 getVal(){
    return 6;
  }
```

And this type of Output you will get 
The sum of 1 + 1 is not 8.